# MYSQL: Select next 100 rows, after a specific value, using alphanumeric Id's

Tags: mysql, sql, jboss, merge, timestamp

I'm merging lots of table entries from one DB to another. I may not merge morge than 100 entries at a time.

I used a timestamp to identify entries, the entries are sorted by time.
So I used to check the timestamp of my last entry and then I merged 100 entries from that point.

Now I got lots of entries with **the same timestamp**. 
(Lets say I got 104 entries with the same timestamp. My application will merge 100 entries and the other entries will be lost.)

Each entry has an individual **random, alphanumeric id**. I thought I could proceed like this:

- get the last entry of my table B,
- check the random string of the last entry
- look for the random id in table A
- get the next 100 entries after that entry.

How can I put this in a query? If this would be a numeric id, I could use this approach
[Select rows after a row with a certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126116/select-rows-after-a-row-with-a-certain-value)

But I have no idea how to select the items after a specific alphanumeric id.

Comment: What does your query look like?

Comment: I tried lots of ways. But I couldn't figure out how to select entries that follow one value with a specific string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Initialize `$offset` and `$current` to 0.
2. Call

   ```
   SELECT stamp, id
   FROM TableA WHERE stamp >= $current
   ORDER BY stamp, id
   LIMIT $offset, 100
   ```
3. Collect the results.
4. Set `$current` to the highest `stamp`
5. Set `$offset` to the number of results with the highest `stamp`.
6. Go back to 2.

Comment: The key to this is ordering by the `id`, so the sort is stable from one call to the next (always produces the same ordering).

Comment: @GordonLinoff Exactly. I almost forgot to put it in.